# How to change the height of one cell independently of other cells in the same row of bootstrap table?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I only know the basics of CSS so not sure how to go about this. I have a table with mostly 1-line data, but the last cell, called "Other", in my first row has multiple lines

Is there a way to make the height small for every cell in the table except that one cell? Right now, because the column with multiple lines is so large, it's making the rest of the cells have extra white space above and below the data (see first screenshot). When I change `line-height` of the `td` it makes the whole table look nice except for that one cell with multiple lines (see second screenshot)

without `line-height`:
[image: first screenshot]

with `line-height` added:
[image: second screenshot]

html (i've left out some `td`'s to make it look cleaner):

```
<table class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">Something</th>
      <th scope="col">Code Version</th>
      <th scope="col">Region</th>
      <th scope="col">Something</th>
      <th scope="col">Something</th>
      <th scope="col">Something->Membership</th>
      <th scope="col">SBMO</th>
      <th scope="col">Something</th>
      <th scope="col">IVR</th>
      <th scope="col">CPM Something</th>
      <th scope="col">Other</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>

<!-- start loop for mongodb collection: environments-->
 <% environments.forEach(function(environment){ %>
    <tr>
        <td>
          <%= environment.something %>
        </td>
        <td>
          <%= environment.codeVersion %>
        </td>
        <td>
          <%= environment.region %>
        </td>

       <!-- other td's go here --->

        <!-- CELL WITH MULTIPLE LINES: -->
        <td class="other">
         <%= environment.other %>
        </td>
 <%}); %> <!-- end loop for environments -->
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

css:

```
.table td {
    padding: 0 !important;
    margin: 0 !important;
    vertical-align: middle;
    border-right: 1px solid #d4d4d4;
}

other {
    white-space: pre-wrap;
}
```

Comment: No, you can't make one cell smaller than the rest. How would that work? The cells would get misaligned. It looks like you might have some extra padding or margins around that text though that you can remove. You can also use rowSpan to let it take over 2 or more cells. Your best option is probably to truncate the text though or put the info into a tooltip.

Comment: Since you can't change the height of a single cell in a table, another simple option is on ALL of your tds, give them ` vertical-align: top;`. This will at least always align the text to the top of the cell and not the middle.

Comment: @mpen I completely forgot about rowspan....that might be what I was looking for!

Comment: @imvain2 I tried ```vertical-align: top``` but it just moved all the whitespace to be below the text :/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rowspan probably won't do what you want either. However, there is an alternative but it isn't `pretty`.

Wrap the content in a div, set its height and set `overflow:scroll`. This will give the content a scroll bar that the user can scroll up and down.

Below is just an example, so you would want to play with the height to display how you want it to.

```
<style>
.other{
height:50px;
overflow:scroll
}
</style>

<td>
<div class="other">
content goes here.
</div>
```

Comment: thank you! this will work for the time being. i didn't know scroll was also something I could use. I think rowspan would work if I could figure out how to only apply it once (since it's in a loop, the rowspan becomes nested and looks awful)

Answer (score 1):

You can also truncate the text (and add an ellipsis) to show that there is more content that what it is shown.

Added simple bonus is that if you add a `title` attribute to the cell, the full contents of the cell can be shown as kind of like a `tooltip`

See demo below:

```css
table {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  max-width: 800px;
}

table td,
table th {
  vertical-align: middle;
  border: 1px solid #d4d4d4;
  width: 100px;
  max-width: 300px;
}

td.other {
  overflow: hidden;
  max-width: 300px;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<h2>sample</h2>
<table class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">Something</th>
      <th scope="col">Code Version</th>
      <th scope="col">Region</th>
      <!--
      <th scope="col">Something</th>
      <th scope="col">Something</th>
      <th scope="col">Something->Membership</th>
      <th scope="col">SBMO</th>
      <th scope="col">Something</th>
      <th scope="col">IVR</th>
      <th scope="col">CPM Something</th>
-->
      <th scope="col">Other</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <!-- start loop for mongodb collection: environments-->
    <tr>
      <td>
        something
      </td>
      <td>
        version
      </td>
      <td>
        region
      </td>

      <!-- other td's go here --->

      <!-- CELL WITH MULTIPLE LINES: -->
      <td class="other" title="other (multi-line) - this is a very long line that should not wrap around the td">
        other (multi-line) - this is a very long line that should not wrap around the td
      </td>
      <!-- end loop for environments -->
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: thanks!! I like the idea of a tooltip but the person I'm working on this project for wants to be able to view all the info at first glance so this wouldn't exactly work for that. I appreciate your help though!

Comment: I understand, client requirements.  Having said that the scroll solution would require you to, well, scroll (which means moving the mouse to the `td` and scroll or click on the scrollbar and drag it/scroll - both would require some user action - imho more work than just hover ;) ) - but I get it, sometimes it's more preference than anything else

Comment: yeah i agree even the scroll is not a perfect solution. if i were doing this for myself i would probably go with a tooltip!

Comment: No worries, glad we could be of help... Don't forget to select the answer that works best for your question.  Have a good day